# Is it possible to allow Flash Socket Client in Android Webview?

Tags: android, flash, sockets, webview

In my project, I need to get some data dynamically from socket server. so i build following app:

App

|----SocketServer

|----WebView

|----HTML

|----Flash Socket Client

My Flash Socket Client need to get Data From User A's app, User B's app. The connection IP list will get from server.

I already sure that :

1.the ServerSocket is work. I can get data from my desktop.

2.Flash is work on my desktop. I can let this flash get data from my android app.

So, here is my question....

Is it possible to allow Flash Socket Client in Webview? if true, how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used wrong way to publish flash. I must set swf permission level in Access network only.

Adobe Learning ActionScript 2.0 in Adobe Flash / Understanding Security / [About local file security and Flash Player](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000457.html#874791)

[My wordpress post has more information and example files](http://zoo.snatalk.com/2011/07/migrate-a-windows-application-to-an-android-app-between-flash-as3-and-java-socket-server/).